# how to obtain quaternion from transformation matrix 4 X 4 in point cloud library c++

Tags: c++, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I have a 4 X 4 transformation matrix obtained from a point cloud and rotation matrix
I need to convert this transformation matrix to quaternion using Eigen::Quaternionf
what should I do?

Comment: You could only convert rotation matrix not transformation to quaternion. You could directly pass your rotation matrix when you construct queaternion.

Comment: then how to obtain the rotation matrix for a certain point cloud read from pcd file

Comment: For that, you'd better show people a minimal workable example of your input file/data and your desirable output.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create an `Eigen::Quaternionf` from a rotation matrix.

```cpp
// mat is a 4x4 transformation matrix
auto rot = mat.block<3,3>(0,0);
Quaternionf q(rot);
```

Comment: can you tell me how to print the output of the quaternion on the screen after that